# How to do regEx in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, regex, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have to create a data frame in which the rows in one column should be a name I extract from a long URL. Let's say I have the following url:

```
https://xxx.xxxxxx.com/xxxxx/y...y/?...?/<irrelevant>
```

Now unfortunately I can't disclose the exact URLs but what I can say is that the letters `x` contain strings that don't change (i.e. all URLs in the database contain those patterns and are known), the `y...y` is an username that is unknown, with unknown length and may change with each URL and the `?...?` is the name in which I am interested in (again a string with unknown length). After that there may be multiple strings separated by `/` which are not useful. How exactly would I do that? Up until now I used to do three different UDFs which use substrings and indexes but I think that's a very cumbersome solution.

I am not very familiar with Regex or with Spark SQL, so even just the regex would be useful.

Thanks

Edit: I think I got the regex down, now I just need to find out how to use it.

```
https:\/\/xxx\.xxxxxx\.com\/xxxxx\/(?:[^0-9\/]+)\/([a-zA-z]*)
```

Comment: Hi. Can you share what code you have tried? Please do so by editing the question

Comment: It's just string manipulation using substring and indexOf. I don't want to use this in the final solution so I don't think it's relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a bit modified your regex. Regex:

```
^https:\/\/www\.example\.com\/user=\/(.*?)\/(.*?)(?:\/.*|$)$
```

It will capture two groups:

- 1st group - username
- 2nd group - some name

You can use `regexp_extract` spark function for selecting regex capture groups. E.g.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

val df = Seq(
    ("https://www.example.com/user=/username1/name3/asd"),
    ("https://www.example.com/user=/username2/name2"),
    ("https://www.example.com/user=/username3/name1/asd"),
    ("https://www.example.com/user=")
).toDF("url")

val r = "^https:\\/\\/www\\.example\\.com\\/user=\\/(.*?)\\/(.*?)(?:\\/.*|$)$"

df.select(
    $"url",
    regexp_extract($"url", r, 1).as("username"),
    regexp_extract($"url", r, 2).as("name")
).show(false)
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
|url                                              |username |name |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
|https://www.example.com/user=/username1/name3/asd|username1|name3|
|https://www.example.com/user=/username2/name2    |username2|name2|
|https://www.example.com/user=/username3/name1/asd|username3|name1|
|https://www.example.com/user=                    |         |     | <- not correct url
+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
```

P.S. you can use regex101.com for validating your regular expressions